# PBE's advantage over DES, 3DES and AES

Tags: java, encryption

I have implemented PBE in addition to DES, 3DES and AES encryption Technique. I am in need of some advantages of PBE over the other three. When I searched on Internet, I am only finding disadvantages. Help me to figure out some advantages of using PBE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand the terminology you are using, PBE means password or pass-phrase based encryption.

According to the sources that I have seen, PBE is a "way of using" some encryption algorithm.  Instead of generating a random key, you take a user-supplied password or pass-phrase and transform that into a key of the form that the encryption system requires (using a "key derivation function").  Here are some references:

- [How does password-based encryption technically work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081403/how-does-password-based-encryption-technically-work)
- [Java 256-bit AES Password-Based Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption)
- [Password based encryption.](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/pbe_key_derivation.shtml)
- [Encrypt/decrypt with DES using a pass phrase](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/crypto/encrypt-decrypt-with-des-using-pass-phrase/).

In other words, if you compare PBE and DES or AES, you are comparing apples and oranges.

So what you are really talking about here is comparing PBE against using a random key.  The advantage of PBE:

- A password or pass-phrase is more memorable than a random key.  (Indeed, a random key is typically so non-memorable that normal humans need to put them into a "key ring" or something ... that is then secured using a password or pass-phrase!)

The disadvantages include:

- A password or pass-phrase is potentially guessable.
- An unsalted password or pass-phrase is potentially vulnerable to attack using "rainbow tables".